# Display 24 hours in a dropdown list using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dropdown list for display time. My Option tag should be something like this

```
<option value="1">01.00AM</option>
<option value="2">02.00AM</option>
<option value="3">03.00AM</option> and so on
```

So Can I know is there a quick way to create the array instead of typing each hours in option tag?

NOTE: AM and PM should be display according to the time.

I tried it with this code, but it doesn't work for me..

```
<select>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
  <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am' ?></option>
<?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Use this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536106/display-list-of-times-from-12pm-to-5am-loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A slight variant on Fresh Prince's deleted answer

I give Fresh Prince of SO most of the credit for this one, but since he deleted his original answer I'm posting a variant of it without the mixed echo tags and weird concatenations.

```
<select id='time'>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++): ?>
    <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= date("h.iA", strtotime("$i:00")); ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

*Note: I am using short echo tags `<?=` because the original post used them. I'd recommend replacing these with `<?php echo` if you're writing portable code that needs to support older versions of PHP.*

**Output format**

The output format from this script is:

```
<select id='time'>
    <option value="1">01.00AM</option>
    <option value="2">02.00AM</option>
    ...
    <option value="23">11.00PM</option>
    <option value="24">12.00AM</option>
</select>
```

[This is a live demo](https://eval.in/46857).

Comment: Sweetie Belle, Can you modify this with `<?php` and `echo`?

Comment: @TNK Replace every instance of `<?=` with `<?php echo`.

Comment: @TNK It will automatically calculate `AM` or `PM` using `strtotime` function.

Comment: with your code it is `AM` - `<option value="24">12.00AM</option>`

Comment: And with @SEMSEM it is `PM` - `<option value="24">12.00PM</option>`

Comment: @TNK My code is correct. `0:00` is `12.00 AM` (midnight). `12:00` is `12.00 PM` (lunch time).

Comment: @TNK SEMSEM's code will display `0:00 AM` (which is technically incorrect) and will never reach 24th hour as it checks if `$i < 24` where I check if `$i <= 24`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36882/discussion-between-tnk-and-sweetie-belle)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

```
date("h.iA", strtotime($i . ":00"))
```

[See a demo](http://codepad.org/4X3R1oJ4)

---

Working it into your example,

```
<?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++):
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">" . date("h.iA", strtotime($i . ":00")) . "</option>\n";
    endfor;
?>
```

---

Alternatively,

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++, $d = date("h.iA", strtotime($i . ":00:00"))) {
       echo "<option value=\"$i\">$d</option>\n";
    }
?>
```

---

Lastly,

```
for($i = 0; $i < 24; print "<option value=\"$i\">" . date("h.iA", strtotime($i . ":00:00")) . "</option>\n", $i++);
```

[See a demo](http://codepad.org/URgTTqLu)

Comment: thanks for quick answer. can you tell me how can I use these function with `for` loop?

Comment: @TNK Did you look at the demo? It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: yes I checked. but problem is when trying to echo it with option tag.

Comment: Don't mix long and short echo tags.

Comment: @SweetieBelle Where am I doing that?

Comment: `<?= $i; ?>"><?php echo ` ... there :)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO What's right with it? It reduces code readability, use one or the other.

Comment: That's pretty subjective. If the OP feels like mixing tag styles then let them.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO OP didn't -- he just uses shorthand `echo` tags.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Changed my +1 to -1. You deleted your good answer and built on your bad one. Will add an answer myself.

Answer (score 1):

No need for all those messy php tags.

```
for ($i=0; $i<24; ++$i) {
  $t = date("H.iA", strtotime($i.":00:00"));
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$t.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I guess it's because it's identical to another answer. not my downvote though.

Comment: Perhaps because it's bad practice to echo out HTML?

Comment: It sure isn't identical. Bad practice? Since when?

Comment: Thanks for the very opinionated claim of bad practice and undeserved downvote! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318033/outputting-html-with-echo-considered-bad-practice-in-php My opinion is that ugly code is ugly. Oh wait...that's a fact..

Comment: @m59 can you please pinpoint the relevant differences? i don't see them.

Comment: @m59 also, first you said that it's not bad practice and then link a question where the accepted answer begins with "I consider it to be bad practice"?

Comment: Because it's a matter of preference. My answer is by far neater than the other answer with the alternate syntax. As there is no performance concern or any other tradeoff, it is just a matter of preference. Objectively, mine is much shorter, especially because I had the sense to separate `$t` to make it easier on the eyes.

Comment: Oh, even better. By this reasoning, the original answer deserves an epic downvote. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @m59 Your answer will give `option value='12:00AM'` not `option value='0'`. Not my downvote but probably the reason.

Comment: Updated. Again, I found the php tags everywhere so distracting that I couldn't tell that was the intent.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following demo:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8y7-hut In-which [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) formating features are used to fill preleading 0.

The following is the code used:

```
<select>
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i+1; ?>"><?php printf('%1$02d.00',(($i+1) > 12)? ($i+1)-12 : $i+1)?><?php echo (($i < 12)? 'AM' : 'PM'); ?></option>
<?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$start = '12:00AM';
$end = '11:59PM';
$interval = '+1 hour';

// $interval = '+30 minutes';
// $interval = '+15 minutes';

$start_str = strtotime($start);
$end_str = strtotime($end);
$now_str = $start_str;

echo '<select>';
while($now_str <= $end_str){
    echo '<option value="' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '">' . date('h:i A', $now_str) . '</option>';
    $now_str = strtotime($interval, $now_str);
}
echo '</select>';
```

[**Here's**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5GIzeE) a working example.